# Programmatically protect media files on sdcard of Android Phone

Tags: android, media, sd-card

My application has to download some media files at runtime. I found that I can store them in internal storage so that only my application can access them.

The problem is that internal storage is limited. Now I want to store media files in sdcard but I want to protect them, so that users can not pull them out of the sdcard and distribute them illegally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this only by encrypt your downloading file with some key , so another application can not access your download file.If you want use that file in your application then you have to decrypt it .There is inbuilt encrypt and decrypt protocol available.(Cipher)

### Note

But encrypt and decrypt has one disadvantage it will take time to decrypt file.